# How to upgrade to Microsoft Edge 13?

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I just wanted to try out new features of JavaScript ES6 in Microsoft Edge 13, but the [VM downloaded](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/mac/) will update Windows, and the Edge is always `20.10240.16384.0` if we go to Settings in Edge and look at the bottom for the version number.

Supposedly, it should be `25.10586` meaning it is Edge 13 (13.10586).  How could we possibly upgrade?